# How can I create a smart collection that checks for only *one* given keyword in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, smart-collections

I think I know my Lightroom pretty well, but I couldn't find a way to create a smart collection that returns photos containing only *one* given keyword. Just one. Say, all photos containing *only* the 'foo' keyword, no other keywords.

The only solution I found was:

1. create a smart collection that returns photos containing that given keyword 'foo',
2. select all photos and add them to *another collection* (say 'temp') for backup,
3. remove the given keyword 'foo' from the photos,
4. create a smart collection that returns the photos containing *no keywords*: this should return all the photos that *only* had the 'foo' keyword before I removed it in the previous step. Unfortunately all photos that had no keywords *before* step 3 will be returned as well, but that's OK, I don't have such photos.
5. do something with the photos returned by step 4, then go to the 'temp' collection and add the 'foo' keyword back.

Tedious.

Comment: I racked my brains but I can't figure out a way to do this; the filtering syntax seems too limited. :-\

Comment: More digging: It seems that in LR3 there's no way to filter for "contains tags that are not X"; you can only do  "does not contain tag X". Without the former, there's no way to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Also there's the obvious missing functionality, "keyword *equals* X" -- you can find keywords containing X, but if you have keywords "peanut" and "peanut butter" you cannot find only the exact match "peanut".

Answer (score 7):

@gerikson:

> I'm sorry, I don't have an answer, I just want to say I wish more tools accepted real SQL as a query language ;)

But technically you *can* do this. The Lightroom catalog is an SQLite database -- try browsing it with Firefox's [SQLite Manager addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), and you'll see it's pretty simple.

You could do this in Lua by writing an extension -- alas, I haven't gone through that step so I'm not sure how to do it.

If you don't need it to be an auto-updating collection the way smart collections work, but rather can deal with running a script every now and then, you could write an external tool to query the SQLite database the way you want, and create a smart collection xml file explicitly including the particular photos in question, and import that into Lightroom. (I needed to do this last bit myself -- see [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/importing-an-external-list-of-photographs-to-lightroom))

---

I just tried this select query and it works great:

```
 SELECT 
    img.id_local AS imageID, 
    kwdef.name AS keyword,
    img.rootFile AS fileID,
    files.originalFilename 
 FROM AgLibraryKeywordImage kwimg
 JOIN Adobe_images img
    ON img.id_local = kwimg.image
 JOIN AgLibraryFile files 
    ON img.rootFile = files.id_local
 JOIN AgLibraryKeyword kwdef
    ON kwdef.id_local = kwimg.tag
 GROUP BY kwimg.image
    HAVING COUNT(*)=1
      AND kwdef.name = ?
```

where you should either replace the ? with a keyword name (e.g. `'foo'`) or execute as a prepared statement. The `GROUP BY` clause does the magic: this groups the results by image, `HAVING COUNT(*)=1` tells SQL to limit its output to images having 1 record.

This query probably won't work quite right for images that have stacks, in which case it needs to be modified to ensure all the `JOIN`s are one-to-one (except for the keyword-image table)

Comment: Yes, you can do that, though I would say the steps I described in my questions are probably simpler, right? Thanks.

Comment: simpler but manual. I have a running grudge against computer software which forces me to repeatedly run through efforts that it could do automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, in LR 4:
keyword contains "mykeyword"
AND
keyword doesn't contain "abcdfghijklnpqstuvxz"

where the 2nd string is all the letters NOT in "mykeyword"

not perfect, but it's a quick and dirty hack that mostly works.

Comment: This was the least worst option for me.  I had to put spaces between the alphabet letters to get this to work.

Comment: This would get even more tedious than OP's original solution if you've got a situation in which some of these images have lots of keywords other than `mykeyword`. In that case, you'd have to manually put in all of the keywords that images that have `mykeyword` also have.

Answer (score 1):

First, go to All Photographs in your catalog and select all of your photos. In the right pane, under Keywording, you will see a text box below Keyword Tags with ALL keywords found (most followed by an asterisk). Copy all of this text and paste it into a text editor.

Now, remove all of the asterisks (I use find/replace to simplify this), as well as the keyword(s) you wish to limit your search to. Once finished, copy all remaining text.

Now, create a smart collection. Add a rule for "Keyword" "Contains" "Single or Multiple Keyword(s) you want to search".

Next, add a rule for "Keyword" "Does not contain" and paste the edited text. Voila. Adobe really should have thought this one through, but it is Adobe...

Comment: ick. And then have to edit that smart collection every time you add a new keyword. :(

Comment: Interesting, unfortunately doesn't work for me, I have a *huge* number of keywords. Copying and pasting them into a text editor and saving the file leads to a 45 *Kb* monster. That's a lot of keywords. Lightroom won't let me enter all of them as a smart collection rule. Interesting idea though, thx.

Answer (score -1):

In theory you should be able to do this with the "starts with" and "ends with" filters. Basically build it as:

```
matches ALL  
keyword  starts with  YourOneKeyWord  
keyword  ends with    YourOneKeyWord
```

But that doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: does this work now with lightroom 3.4? i have set up a smart collection using "starts with" and "ends with" "flickr", and it is returning only those photos with exactly "flickr", excluding a photo that i had with the dummy keyword "flickrzzz".

Comment: no, even with LR 3.5 this still fails. I'm not sure how but Adobe's definition of "beginsWith" doesn't seem to match the one most folks would use.